# JS switch value onclick

Tags: javascript

I've an array thats downloaded from php to JS with paths to images, i want to switch the value on clicking the arrow image, -1 for left and +1 for right, my code doesn't seem to work tho.

```js
<script>
    var urls = <?php echo json_encode($urls); ?>;
    var i = 4;

    function goleft(){
        if (i > 1) {
            i = i - 1;
            return i;
        }
    }

    document.write('<div id=showcase><a id=leftslide><img onclick=goleft() src=images/left.png></a><img id=bigpic src='+urls[i]+'></div>');
</script>
```

`img src=images/left.png` is the left arrow.
`urls[i]` is what i want to change onclick an make it interactive

Comment: It's better if you copy the output of the PHP variable to your question instead of that `echo`, since the issue isn't about your PHP (and we can then see what the variable actually contains). Just do a "view source" and copy it from there.

Comment: You say you want to change it, so `document.write` is not the way to go. This way, you're just adding new elements (plus, it's invalid markup, as you're creating elements with the same id). What you need is to replace the href of a specific anchor tag (the one with `leftslide` id and, I assume, another one with `rightslide`).

Comment: The array in php is downloading the information from the database which is dynamic, the array itself is fine but the variable ' i ' doesn't change onclick.

As for what's in it here is the print_r() of that array:
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; images/gallery/gallery.6033b6b874f379.43670787.png
    [1] =&gt; images/gallery/gallery.6033b6b1789f26.78091433.png
    [2] =&gt; images/gallery/gallery.6033b647c4e3c4.28149712.jpg
    [3] =&gt; images/gallery/gallery.6033b641a196c1.70869595.jpg
    [4] =&gt; images/gallery/gallery.6033b633cba9c3.01276752.jpg
...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for guiding me to solution, it works with jquery now.

```
  var urls = <?php echo json_encode($urls); ?>;              
  var i = 4;
        function goleft(){
            if (i > 1) {
            i = i - 1;
            $("#bigpic").attr("src",urls[i]);
                                }
                            }           
                </script>
<div id=showcase><a id=leftslide><img onclick=goleft() src=images/left.png></a><img id=bigpic src=></div>
```